# Access multiple nodes of XML document for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an XML doc like this:

```
DROP TABLE #temp
create table #temp (xml_data xml)

insert into #temp (xml_data) values
('<UPDATE><ENTITY DN="test"><ATTRIBUTE N="test name" V="test value" />     </ENTITY></UPDATE>')

select C.value('@DN', 'varchar(max)') as [ENTITY.DN]
      ,C.value('@N', 'varchar(max)') as [ATTRIBUTE.N]
      ,C.value('@V', 'varchar(max)') as [ATTRIBUTE.V]
from #temp cross apply
     #temp.xml_data.nodes('UPDATE/ENTITY') as X(C)
```

My output ends up like this:

```
test | NULL | NULL
```

I'd like to see:

```
test | test name | test value
```

Any thoughts on how I've configured this incorrectly?

Comment: I think I answered my own question.  Would this be the correct way to do what I want?


    `DROP TABLE #temp
     create table #temp (xml_data xml)

     insert into #temp (xml_data) values
('<UPDATE><ENTITY DN="test"><ATTRIBUTE N="test name" V="test value" /></ENTITY></UPDATE>')

select C.value('@DN', 'varchar(max)') as [ENTITY.DN]
      ,r.value('@N', 'varchar(max)') as [ATTRIBUTE.N]
      ,r.value('@V', 'varchar(max)') as [ATTRIBUTE.V]
from #temp cross apply
     #temp.xml_data.nodes('UPDATE/ENTITY') as X(C)
  cross apply
  #temp.xml_data.nodes('UPDATE/ENTITY/ATTRIBUTE') as Y(r)`

Comment: No. check for 2 entities

Comment: insert into #temp (xml_data) values ('<UPDATE><ENTITY DN="test"><ATTRIBUTE N="test name" V="test value" /> </ENTITY> <ENTITY DN="test1"><ATTRIBUTE N="test name1" V="test value1" /> </ENTITY> </UPDATE>')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case one `ENTITY` might have multiple `ATTRIBUTE` child -based on your comment-, you'll need another `APPLY` to shred on `ATTRIBUTE`, for example :

```
declare @temp table(xml_data xml)
insert into @temp (xml_data) values
('<UPDATE>
  <ENTITY DN="test">
    <ATTRIBUTE N="test name" V="test value"/> 
    <ATTRIBUTE N="foo1" V="bar1"/>
    <ATTRIBUTE N="foo2" V="bar2"/>
  </ENTITY>
</UPDATE>')

select ent.value('@DN', 'varchar(max)') as [ENTITY.DN]
      ,attr.value('@N', 'varchar(max)') as [ATTRIBUTE.N]
      ,attr.value('@V', 'varchar(max)') as [ATTRIBUTE.V]
from @temp t 
     cross apply t.xml_data.nodes('UPDATE/ENTITY') as X(ent)
     cross apply ent.nodes('./ATTRIBUTE') as Y(attr)
```

**<kbd>[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/4812)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
| ENTITY.DN | ATTRIBUTE.N | ATTRIBUTE.V |
|-----------|-------------|-------------|
|      test |   test name |  test value |
|      test |        foo1 |        bar1 |
|      test |        foo2 |        bar2 |
```

Comment: Thanks to all but this is the answer that satisfied my issue.  Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

change to this

```
DROP TABLE #temp
create table #temp (xml_data xml)

insert into #temp (xml_data) values
('<UPDATE><ENTITY DN="test"><ATTRIBUTE N="test name" V="test value" />     </ENTITY></UPDATE>')

select C.value('@DN', 'varchar(max)') as [ENTITY.DN]
      ,C.value('ATTRIBUTE[1]/@N', 'varchar(max)') as [ATTRIBUTE.N]
      ,C.value('ATTRIBUTE[1]/@V', 'varchar(max)') as [ATTRIBUTE.V]
from #temp cross apply
     #temp.xml_data.nodes('UPDATE/ENTITY') as X(C)
```

Comment: And your code is going to break if there is ever a `<ENTITY>` node with more than one `<ATTRIBUTE>` subnode .....

Comment: What if there were more attributes inside the entity tag @DimaSum?  

insert into #temp (xml_data) values
('<UPDATE><ENTITY DN="test"><ATTRIBUTE N="test name" V="test value" /><ATTRIBUTE N="test2 name" V="test2 val" /></ENTITY></UPDATE>')

Answer (score 0):

The answer DimaSUN provided will work. Here is an alternative query:

```
SELECT xml_data.query('data(/UPDATE/ENTITY/@DN)') as [ENTITY.DN],
        xml_data.query('data(/UPDATE/ENTITY/ATTRIBUTE/@N)') as [ATTRIBUTE.N],
        xml_data.query('data(/UPDATE/ENTITY/ATTRIBUTE/@V)') as [ATTRIBUTE.V]
    FROM #temp;
```

Comment: Check u'rs answer against 2..N entities. U'll get wrong result... :(

Comment: insert into #temp (xml_data) values
('<UPDATE><ENTITY DN="test"><ATTRIBUTE N="test name" V="test value" />     </ENTITY>
<ENTITY DN="test1"><ATTRIBUTE N="test name1" V="test value1" />     </ENTITY>
</UPDATE>')